# How to dismiss showmodalbottomsheet and textfield all at once?

Tags: flutter

As you all can see, I have a textfield wrapped in a scaffold widget. All of that is wrapped in a showmodalbottomsheet. When i dismiss the system's keyboard when it is focused, the showmodalbottomsheet is still there. How can i dismiss the showmodallbottomsheet along with everything wrapped inside of it when i dismiss the textfield? Here is my code:

Future BottomSheet()
{
return showModalBottomSheet(
isScrollControlled: true,

```
  context: context,
  builder:



      (
      BuildContext context) {
    ////////////////////////////////////////////

    return FractionallySizedBox(
      heightFactor: 0.39,
      child: Scaffold(

        //resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        //backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        body:

        Container(

          height: 40,//_controller.focusNode.value.hasFocus ? MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom + 200 : 0,

          //height: 40,
          width: width * 0.95,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
            border: Border.all(
              width: 1,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding:   EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, bottom: height*0.005),
            child:

            TextField(
              autofocus: true,
              onTap: () {

              },

              focusNode: anonymityController.focusNode.value,
              cursorColor: Colors.black38,
              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              //focusNode: _controller.focusNode.value,//openingPage.focusNode,
              onChanged: (value) {


              },
              controller: textEditingController,
              decoration:  InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'write something',

                //  openingPage.replyAuthor ?? "Write or say something on this"  ,
                hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white70, fontSize: 15),
                border: InputBorder.none,
              ),

            ),


          ),
        ),

      ),
    );

    ///////////////////////////


  }
```

);
}